# How can I make a RichTextBox from a simple TextBox?

Tags: c#

The problem is that I want to change the color of the text from a textBox and I cannot use .SelectionColor because my textBox is not a RichTextBox. 
Thank you.

Comment: Use a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: yeah, but the thing is it just gives me an error that says: 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectionColor' and no extension method 'SelectionColor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Um, you __know__ you have picked the wrong control and __ask__ us what to do about it? Really?

Comment: 1. Delete the `TextBox` control you are currently using. 2. Put a `RichTextBox` in it's place. 3. Profit

Comment: If you want to change **ALL** of the Text in your `TextBox` to the **SAME** color then use the [ForeColor()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez1ywchy(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  If you want multiple colors then you need to switch to a [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) as the others have already stated.